# Justifying $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial m^n} x^m dx=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial m^n}\int_{0}^{1} x^m dx$

Tags: integration, derivatives

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^m (\log(x))^n dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial m^n} x^m dx=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial m^n}\int_{0}^{1} x^m dx$$

How can I justify the last step I made there? Dominate convergence theorem?

Comment: Differentiation under the integral sign (which does follow from the dominated convergence theorem). See, for instance, Bartle’s *The elements of integration and Lebesgue Measure*, or Google it.

Comment: I don't see how you can. The integrand on the left is not uniformly continuous, the integrand on the right is.

Comment: Transform both integrals with $u=-\ln x$; the use of differentiation under an integral will then be easier to justify.